# Retrieving occluded faces given a rectangular region

Tags: opengl

I am trying to do a click-and-drag selection to select all the visible faces of a model (similar to those in 3D modelling software such as Blender).

Initially I am thinking of using line intersection to find all the occluded faces in the scene: for every pixel in the viewport, trace a line into the scene and find the first intersection. Then the list of occluded faces would be the ones that did not get intersected. But then after experimentation I realized that this method is very slow.

I heard of another method which goes something like:

1. Assigning a unique color for each primitive.
2. Project all those onto a virtual plane coincides with the viewport
3. From the projected pixels, if the colors corresponding to a primitive are not present, then it is occluded.

The problem is that I have no idea how to go about creating such a "virtual" plane, and at the same time not revealing it to the end-user. Any help or better idea to solve this?

Comment: the term to search for is "framebuffer"

Comment: Search for OpenGL picking hack